# ¿Cómo ajustar el contenido de un formulario al cambio de tamaño?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

¿Cómo ajustar el contenido de un formulario al cambio de tamaño?

Estaba trabajando con el tamaño del formulario que sale por defecto, pero al compilarlo cuando le doy maximizar los controles que salen en el conservan su posición y tamaño, dando un aspecto poco estético. La idea es que el contenido dentro del formulario se escale según se cambie el tamaño del formulario, bien sea al Ajustar, Maximizar o al desplazar el mouse desde una esquina.

Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Deberás establecer la propiedad de los controles AutoSize en true y jugar con la propiedad Anchor (Top, Bottom, Left, Right) dependiendo de los resultados que quieras esperar. Puedes hacerlo mediante el editor de propiedades o mediante:

```
        control.AutoSize = true;
        control.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom| AnchorStyles.Right;
```